# Gnuplot: ternary operation on dates to filter data

Tags: gnuplot, ternary

I have data files with the following format:

2012-02-05 2

2012-02-06 5

...

...

2012-02-10 11

I want to plot the data that is say, greater than 2012-02-08. I tried the following ternary operation but, it does not work

plot 'datafile1' using 1:(strcol(1) gt "2012-02-08" ? $2 : 1/0) title "a" with lp lw 5,\

'datafile2' using 1:(strcol(1) gt "2012-02-08" ? $2 : 1/0) title "b" with lp lw 5

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, found that this can be achieved by manually setting the xrange values. Still, will be interested to know if a ternary operator for comparing dates in gnuplot exist.

Answer (score 0):

The gnuplot manual has some functions that might work for you:

```
timecolumn(x) 
tm_hour(x) 
tm_mday(x) 
tm_min(x) 
tm_mon(x)
```

From page 27 of the [gnuplot 4.6 manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf)